# Zabbix agent не подключается к серверу

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, zabbix, hyper-v

Агент заббикса не видит сервер, пинг есть. Если поставить агент на самом сервере тогда он сам себя видит и агент отображается. Пробовал настроить на коммутаторе внутреннюю сеть для обеих машин, так же видят друг друга, но агент не работает.

Такая конфигурация: 
- Windows 10 с отключенным фаерволом
- Установлен Hyper-V, в нём настроен виртуальный коммутатор (external).
- Виртуальная машина Ubuntu 17.04 , Zabbix 3.2.0.

[image: вот так это выглядит в заббиксе]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить шаблон к хосту. Судя по картинке, у Вас это поле пустое.

Configuration -> Hosts -> "Нужный хост" -> Templates -> Select -> "Нужный шаблон" -> Select -> Add -> Update

После чего, на всякий случай, перезапустите zabbix-agent.

Comment: Спасибо, если честно я уже снес всё , т.к. планы изменились. Но в любом случае спасибо